# How to implement support vector machine in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm

I am new to machine learning (not a mathematician)  and learning ML myself from videos and books. I have a basic understanding of naive bayes , svm, decision tree etc algorithm and I am using ML to model the stock market daily return. I want to use a non linear regression algorithm for my ML so chose **support vector machine regression** because of its popularity. I used day of the trading and EMA difference as feature vector (X) and price change as label (Y). Below is my code

```
library("quantmod")
#Adding libraries
library("lubridate")
#Makes it easier to work with the dates 
library("e1071")
#Gives us access to the svm
stockData <- new.env()
tickers <- 'AAPL'
startDate = as.Date("2015-11-01")
# The beginning of the date range we want to look at 


symbol = getSymbols(tickers,from=startDate, auto.assign=F)
# Retrieving Apple’s daily OHLCV from Yahoo Finance 
DayofWeek<-wday(symbol, label=TRUE)
#Find the day of the week 
Class<- Cl(symbol) - Op(symbol)
#price change
EMA5<-EMA(Cl(symbol),n = 5)
#We are calculating a 5-period EMA off the open price

EMA10<-EMA(Cl(symbol),n = 10)
#Then the 10-period EMA, also off the open price 
EMACross <- EMA5 - EMA10
#Positive values correspond to the 5-period EMA being above the 10-period EMA 

EMACross<-round(EMACross,2)


DataSet2<-data.frame(DayofWeek,EMACross, Class)
DataSet2<-DataSet2[-c(1:10),]
#We need to remove the instances where the 10-period moving average is still being calculated
m<-nrow(DataSet2)
n<-round((nrow(DataSet2)*2)/3)
TrainingSet<-DataSet2[1:n,]
#We will use ⅔ of the data to train the model
TestSet<-DataSet2[(n+1):m,]
#And ⅓ to test it on unseen data 
EMACrossModel<-svm( Cl(symbol) ~ ., data=TrainingSet) 
summary(EMACrossModel)
pred<-predict(EMACrossModel,TestSet[,-3])
```

when I run the above code i am getting this error

```
> EMACrossModel<-svm( Cl(symbol) ~ ., data=TrainingSet) 
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Cl(symbol) ~ ., data = TrainingSet,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'DayofWeek')
```

So my questions are (forgive me but i have more than one question)

```
1) How to solve my above problem?

2) Can in use both qualitative (eg: mon,tue,wed etc) and quantitative(eg 1.0,0.1,100 etc) data together in SVM regressions 

3) How can i plot my above results with SVM decision
boundaries?
```

**EDITED**

DataSet2

```
          DayofWeek   EMA AAPL.Close
2015-11-16       Mon -2.77   2.800003
2015-11-17      Tues -2.51  -1.229996
2015-11-18       Wed -1.67   1.529999
2015-11-19     Thurs -0.89   1.140000
2015-11-20       Fri -0.32   0.100006
2015-11-23       Mon -0.23  -1.519997
2015-11-24      Tues  0.00   1.549995
2015-11-25       Wed  0.00  -1.180000
2015-11-27       Fri -0.03  -0.480003
2015-11-30       Mon  0.02   0.310005
2015-12-01      Tues -0.09  -1.410004
2015-12-02       Wed -0.31  -1.059997
2015-12-03     Thurs -0.57  -1.350006
2015-12-04       Fri -0.10   3.739998
2015-12-07       Mon  0.05  -0.700004
2015-12-08      Tues  0.12   0.710006
2015-12-09       Wed -0.24  -2.019996
2015-12-10     Thurs -0.35   0.129997
2015-12-11       Fri -0.83  -2.010002
2015-12-14       Mon -1.15   0.300003
2015-12-15      Tues -1.56  -1.450004
2015-12-16       Wed -1.56   0.269996
2015-12-17     Thurs -1.82  -3.039994
2015-12-18       Fri -2.30  -2.880005
2015-12-21       Mon -2.23   0.050003
2015-12-22      Tues -2.07  -0.169999
2015-12-23       Wed -1.64   1.340004
2015-12-24     Thurs -1.40  -0.970001
2015-12-28       Mon -1.37  -0.769996
2015-12-29      Tues -0.98   1.779999
2015-12-30       Wed -0.92  -1.260002
```

the below code after modification runs but giving different answer

these are the modifications

```
EMACrossModel<-ksvm(  Cl(symbol[1:n]) ~ ., data=TrainingSet,kernel="rbfdot",C=10) #kernlab libraries

pred<-predict(EMACrossModel,TestSet)
```

result

```
> EMACrossModel
Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

SV type: eps-svr  (regression) 
 parameter : epsilon = 0.1  cost C = 10 

Gaussian Radial Basis kernel function. 
 Hyperparameter : sigma =  0.294836572886287 

Number of Support Vectors : 17 

Objective Function Value : -49.1082 
Training error : 0.138329 

> pred
          [,1]
 [1,] 119.7267
 [2,] 119.9733
 [3,] 120.7236
 [4,] 121.8324
 [5,] 121.5632
 [6,] 121.4652
 [7,] 119.6438
 [8,] 119.6962
 [9,] 119.0775
[10,] 116.4956
```

I except prediction results to be like this

```
     [,1]
-1.327996
1.229939
-1.130000
0.100006
-1.519997
-0.480003
 1.310005
-1.410004
-1.059997
1.350006
-2.739998
1.700004
```

My guess is that my current code take stock price instead of price change as Y and use it to model **EMACrossModel**. Am i right? if yes how can i solve this problem.

Comment: You could make help easier if you would provide a smaller dataset. This way it is necessary to install additional libraries.

Comment: In training your are specifying Cl(symbol[1:n]) as target vector. 
If you specify as written in my answer: EMACrossModel<-svm( AAPL.Close ~ ., data=TrainingSet)  you get results similar to the ones you expect.
I added the predictions below

Comment: Added also a few lines on the formula aspect which defines what is learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning question one
You formed your Trainingset by removing some data. However, you didn't restrict you symbol set:

```
 EMACrossModel<-svm( Cl(symbol[1:n]) ~ ., data=TrainingSet)
```

I just realise what you more likely want to have is:

```
 EMACrossModel<-svm( AAPL.Close ~ ., data=TrainingSet)
```

In general the formula:
 Cl(symbol[1:n]) ~ .
defines what is learned. currently it is the "symbol". However, I assume you want to predict the column AAPL.Close. 
Formulas are general concept in R (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/formula.html). It is worthwhile to invest a bit of time in understanding these.
**EDIT**
based on your above comment this seems to be confirmed. The results are then

```
-0.1926745  
0.3578645  
0.1830046  
0.6362871 
-0.3760084 
-0.1443156  
0.2615674  
0.2589130 
-0.4779677 
-0.5928780
```

**END EDIT**

Concerning question two it depends on the implementation (and the kernel) but here it seems to be the case.

Concerning your third question. The E1071 package contains an example:

```
data(cats, package = "MASS")
m <- svm(Sex~., data = cats)
plot(m, cats)
```

**EDIT**
I just realised this plot function works only for classifiers but not for regression. However, you can easily build your own plotting function. For simplicity, I first converted the days of week into numbers.

```
  DataSet2$DayofWeek <- as.numeric(DataSet2$DayofWeek)
```

and rebuild the classifier
Afterwards you can visualise the classifier by

```
### plot the results of the support vector machine by
# first generating a grid covering the data range

#generate a sequence of 100 numbers between the minimum and maximum of DataSet2EMA 
plot.ema.vec <- seq(min(DataSet2$EMA),max(DataSet2$EMA),(max(DataSet2$EMA)-min(DataSet2$EMA))/100)
#generate a "grid" of artificial data points 1:7 are the weekdays
# can be replaced by c("Mon",...,"Sun")
datagrid <- expand.grid(1:7,plot.ema.vec)
# set the names of the grid according to the dataset s.t. the classifier can use the data as input
names(datagrid) <- names(DataSet2[,1:2])
#calculate the predictions of the classifier
grid.pred <- predict(EMACrossModel,datagrid)
# normalise the prediction in [0,1] range to use it as colors
cols <- (grid.pred-min(grid.pred))/(max(grid.pred)-min(grid.pred))
# plot the decisions for the data 
plot(datagrid$DayofWeek,datagrid$EMA , col=rgb(blue=cols,red=1-cols,green=0))
```

Comment: hey thanks for the help :). it worked but can you explain a little bit more about your last lines for plotting. `plot.ema.vec <- seq(min(DataSet2$EMA),max(DataSet2$EMA),(max(DataSet2$EMA)...` what is happening in those codes. I am not able to understand the logic behind the plotting.

Comment: I added some comments describing the procedure.